# How to divide a numerical columns in ranges and assign labels for each range in apache spark?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hivecontext

I have the following sparkdataframe:

```
id weekly_sale
1    40000
2    120000
3    135000
4    211000
5    215000
6    331000
7    337000
```

I need to see in which of the following intervals items in weekly_sale column fall:

```
under 100000
between 100000 and 200000
between 200000 and 300000
more than 300000
```

so my desired output would be like:

```
id weekly_sale  label
1    40000       under 100000    
2    120000      between 100000 and 200000
3    135000      between 100000 and 200000
4    211000      between 200000 and 300000
5    215000      between 200000 and 300000
6    331000      more than 300000
7    337000      more than 300000
```

any pyspark, spark.sql and Hive context implementation will help me.

Comment: @ eliasah i'd appreciate your help

Comment: So have you tried anything? There are many ways to achieve these and none is particularly complex.

Comment: @zero323 actually i am just thinking to register DF as a table and then use CASE WHEN .. what is your idea?

Comment: Assuming you have got just 4 cases, you can just invoke map on RDD and transform those ints into strings with if statements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming ranges and labels are defined as follows:

```py
splits = [float("-inf"), 100000.0, 200000.0, 300000.0, float("inf")]
labels = [
    "under 100000", "between 100000 and 200000", 
    "between 200000 and 300000", "more than 300000"]

df = sc.parallelize([
    (1, 40000.0), (2, 120000.0), (3, 135000.0),
    (4, 211000.0), (5, 215000.0), (6, 331000.0),
    (7, 337000.0)
]).toDF(["id", "weekly_sale"])
```

one possible approach is to use `Bucketizer`:

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import Bucketizer
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, col, lit

bucketizer = Bucketizer(
    splits=splits, inputCol="weekly_sale", outputCol="split"
)

with_split = bucketizer.transform(df)
```

and attach labels later:

```py
label_array = array(*(lit(label) for label in labels))

with_split.withColumn(
    "label", label_array.getItem(col("split").cast("integer"))
).show(10, False)

## +---+-----------+-----+-------------------------+
## |id |weekly_sale|split|label                    |
## +---+-----------+-----+-------------------------+
## |1  |40000.0    |0.0  |under 100000             |
## |2  |120000.0   |1.0  |between 100000 and 200000|
## |3  |135000.0   |1.0  |between 100000 and 200000|
## |4  |211000.0   |2.0  |between 200000 and 300000|
## |5  |215000.0   |2.0  |between 200000 and 300000|
## |6  |331000.0   |3.0  |more than 300000         |
## |7  |337000.0   |3.0  |more than 300000         |
## +---+-----------+-----+-------------------------+
```

There are of course different ways you can achieve the same goal. For example you can create a lookup table:

```py
from toolz import sliding_window
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast

mapping = [
    (lower, upper, label) for ((lower, upper), label)
    in zip(sliding_window(2, splits), labels)
]

lookup_df =sc.parallelize(mapping).toDF(["lower", "upper", "label"])

df.join(
    broadcast(lookup_df),
    (col("weekly_sale") >= col("lower")) & (col("weekly_sale") < col("upper"))
).drop("lower").drop("upper")
```

or generate lookup expression:

```py
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

def in_range(c):
    def in_range_(acc, x):        
        lower, upper, label = x
        return when(
            (c >= lit(lower)) & (c < lit(upper)), lit(label)
        ).otherwise(acc)
    return in_range_

label = reduce(in_range(col("weekly_sale")), mapping, lit(None))

df.withColumn("label", label)
```

The least efficient approach is an UDF.

Comment: i am going to test it, thanks a lot , i was trying when otherwise function but it seems that when only takes one condition, how can i give it several conditions? df_label= quantile_filtered.withColumn("label", func.when(quantile_filtered.total_sale<100000 , "under 100000").otherwise(0))

Comment: how do you evaluate this one:df_label= quantile_filtered.withColumn("label", func.when(quantile_filtered.total_sale<3500, "under 3500").when((quantile_filtered.total_sale>=3500) &  (quantile_filtered.total_sale<3800) , "3500 to 3800").when((quantile_filtered.total_sale>=3800)&(quantile_filtered.total_sale<6000),"3800 to 6000").when(quantile_filtered.total_sale>=6000,"above 6000"))

Comment: No action as you see

Comment: So there is nothing to evaluate. I am not sure if I understand what you want here.

Comment: @ zero323 maybe i used the wrong word , what i meant was that  how do you compare my solution with your solutions